# C# Data Contract Class - Extend / Add Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web, asp.net-core-webapi

I have taken over a new project where we have a Web API that returns data from the back-end database. We have used Data Contract classes to model our objects to each table that we return. My question is around extending what is returned so that we can display additional data on the front-end that is not held in the database. Here is an example of the class:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class ContainersInPort
{

    [DataMember] public string ContainerNumberFull { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string PortLocationId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string PortLocation { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string PortName { get; set; }

}
```

Is there any way I can add a new property to the class above? I have added the following line of code to my class but it returned an out of range exception error.

```
public string FrontEndProperty { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to add essentially add attributes without causing the exception and use the same object with the Web API data and any other properties that be added before displaying on front-end.

Comment: You can always add properties to objects. There's something else going on that's not in your question. What exactly is throwing an out of range exception?

Comment: Share us the complete code which cause this error? You may define a new model which inherits from `ContainersInPort`, and append new properties to new model, then return the new model with your expected data.